# Converting anchor text into list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor text which I want to split and convert into list items (bullet points)

Here I use jquery to get text of the specific anchors:

```
var productDetails = $('.product-info .product-name').find('a');

console.log(productDetails.text());
```

which results in this list:

```
Whiteboard 80x110 cm - Magnetisch
Whiteboard 60x90 cm - Magnetisch
Whiteboard 60x90 cm - Magnetisch / Emaille
Whiteboard 90x120 cm - Magnetisch / Emaille
Skin Whiteboard 75x115 cm - Wit
Skin Whiteboard 75x115 cm PRO - Polyester coating
Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 58x88 cm
Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 78x108 cm
Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 88x118 cm
Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 88x178 cm
```

How can I split these into the following:

- Whiteboard
- 80x110 cm
- Magnetisch

Hope somebody can help me out because I really don't know how to split the string. Most logical is to split it at the first number and the `-` dash.

What I tried is to split it like this:

```
console.log(productDetails.split("-"), productDetails.match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
```

which results in an array of text with splitted the last word like this:

```
0:" Whiteboard 80x110 cm "
1:" Magnetisch                Whiteboard 60x90 cm "
```

and an array with all the numbers splitted like this:

```
0:80
1:110
```

But how can I make an nice splitting so that I don't have to combine this output.

Comment: your naming convention is inconsistent so i don't think this is possible,  better if you do this on the server side

Comment: Maybe you don't know how to, but you have to try something. Show us your attempt. Try something with String.split().

Comment: You can split using regular expression. But since you have a non-consistent output, it is hard to achieve

Comment: @madalinivascu thats not possible because it is an AB Test which I am doing with Google tag manager.

Comment: Does anybody knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `regular expression` and string `split`. Because your data is non-consistent, there isn't a clean way to do this. One approach is e.g.

```
 1. Split the output on the dimension, i.e. `58x88 cm`
 2. Remove all white spaces and dashes
 3. Concat the result
```

Here is a sample code

```js
var input = [
    'Whiteboard 80x110 cm - Magnetisch',
    'Whiteboard 60x90 cm - Magnetisch',
    'Whiteboard 60x90 cm - Magnetisch / Emaille',
    'Whiteboard 90x120 cm - Magnetisch / Emaille',
    'Skin Whiteboard 75x115 cm - Wit',
    'Skin Whiteboard 75x115 cm PRO - Polyester coating',
    'Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 58x88 cm',
    'Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 78x108 cm',
    'Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 88x118 cm',
    'Frameless whiteboard - Rechte hoeken - 88x178 cm',
];

function trimCharacters(s) {
    return s.replace(/^(\s|-)+|(\s|-)+$/g, '')
}

function bulletList(text) {
    if (!text) {
        return;
    }
    var items = text.split(/(\d+x\d+ cm)/).filter(Boolean).map(x => trimCharacters(x));
    if (items.length === 3) {
        return items;
    }
    var res = items[0].split('-').map(item => trimCharacters(item));

    return [res[0], items[1], res[1]];
}

input.forEach(text => {
    var data = bulletList(text);
    var list = $('<ul></ul>');
    
    data.forEach(item => {
        list.append(`<li>${item}</li>`);
    });

    $('.data-list').append(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data-list"></div>
```

**NOTE**: because your data is non-consistent, this code only works for the provided pattern.
Also this code is written in `Ecmascript` so you would probably want to *transpile* it to normal javascript for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
var main_array=[];
$('.product-info .product-name a').each(function(){
var array=$(this).text().split(" ");
main_array.push(array);
});

console.log(main_array);
```

main_array will have the string, use index syntax to access the required string.

Comment: This doesn't help in any way. Read again and compare what the OP wants and what your snippet does.

Comment: output is not consistent. its hard to achieve

Comment: Yes, we know that. That was already stated out in OPs post, but what you posted isn't a solution to OPs problem. You just show off how to split a string.

Comment: is it possible to have some delimiter in 'a' tag so that we can split it using delimiter for example "|".

Comment: @KaleemNalband what do you mean I cant edit the string this is what I get from the website. We can edit it afterwards

Comment: @KaleemNalband you know any solution?

Comment: @KaleemNalband check out my solution

Comment: @onyx it looks great!